# Need a media subdirectory inside a nomedia folder

Tags: media-files, media-scanner, hidden

As the title says, I have been searching for a way to show pictures from a nomedia folder subdirectory...the files have to be in that directory and can't be moved.

My messaging app stores it's background images  from themes into it's own directory. I have that directory hidden with .nomedia. However, it also stores any downloaded pictures into a media subdirectory and doesn't have the option to change that. I need the downloads to show in the gallery but not all the themes, if there's any way to do this

[image]

Comment: Try adding .scanmedia tag in that folder and see if it works. If not, try rebooting

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. I've never found a way to get it to show.  Just factory reset a week ago and clear dalvic periodically, but it's never displayed. When I removed .nomedia from the main directory to see, the main directory displayed after running a media scanner, but that subdirectory still never showed.  Don't know if there's a limited depth of subdirectories that will display, and if there is, how to change it. The folder they're in is 3 down from the main folder. I can't see any reason there would be a limit though.